# Easy pie chart not appearing

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to have a pie chart section that animated when it is scrolled to , however my chart does not appear.  I downloaded the source files for it and those seem to work fine ecept when i move the jquery.easypiechart.js to my JS folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

    <link id="main" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

<body>
<section id="span">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row span">

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                    <span class="chart" data-percent="80"><span class="percent">80</span></span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                    <span class="chart" data-percent="70"><span class="percent">70</span></span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                    <span class="chart" data-percent="60"><span class="percent">60</span></span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                    <span class="chart" data-percent="90"><span class="percent">90</span></span>

                </div>

            </div><!--End row -->

        </div><!--End container -->

    </section><!--End skills section -->


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script src='js/jquery.flexslider.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

$('#span').waypoint(function(){
    $('.chart').each(function(){
    $(this).easyPieChart({
            size:170,
            animate: 2000,
            lineCap:'butt',
            scaleColor: false,
            barColor: '#ccc',
            lineWidth: 10
        });
    });
},{offset:'80%'});






}); </script>



</body>
```

Comment: Are you including it correctly?  Do you have any errors on your console?

Comment: Not that i can see 
im using <script src="js/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>

Comment: I am attempting to follow the same methodology as this website however with no luck.

http://q-themes.net/themes/designr/

from what i can see its using Jquery waypoints to stigger the animaton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make absolutely sure that all the required files are included and accessible.  Right click on your page and click "View Source" or "View Page Source"  then open each "script" listed in the source by clicking on its `src` to make sure you can load it first.

The order should be

1. jQuery.js (at least 1.7.2)
2. waypoints.js
3. easypiechat.js

Then everything should work fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/JxvE9/2/

Comment: For some reason my code is only working when i have included flexslider :/

Comment: The demo I posted above however *does* work without flex slider?  At least you've got your stuff working.  Do you also know that `waypoints` is/are only really useful if your page is quite long as for example on the demo the charts instantiate immediately due to the page being short.

Comment: Apologies Rob im just trying to figure out what i did wrong in the first place.

Comment: No need to apologise but I have shown you that it works without flexslider so there must be something else in your page that has a dependency on that.

Comment: Should these files be in the head? I'm stil new to JQuery 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14168066/portfolio_new/index.html

Comment: Using dropbox it's not loading all the referenced files unfortunately.   But it doesn't matter particularly whether they're in the head or footer, however it does matter to your page-load-time thus SEO position and how your page looks. :-( Rather use jsfiddle.net than dropbox for these things.  Your URL's are `relative` which means that they are trying to load from dropbox.  If you are wanting to serve them from a CDN, then enter the full URL's otherwise change the hosting setup as I don't think dropbox allows you to reference other files per se.

Comment: SO its drop box causing it maybe ill test it locally and get back to you thank you for your help

Comment: Perhaps it is Dropbox, I suggest testing locally yes.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly on my local environment. Is there any way i can delay te animation until the div hits my navbar? I had planed on having the Text fad in with JSWOW then the animation trigger

Comment: Ok thanks for the help Rob ill look into it , i apologise if i seem little slow im still getting used to Jquery.